# Google Web App - Using e.parameter passing to select Select option (Materialize CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, materialize

Over the last few days been trying to pass variables from a Google Sheet to a few Select options within a Google Web App Html page via e.parameter. Have managed to use this method to pass variables to text inputs on this web page within the doGet().

Successfully passing Text Inputs:

Within doGet()

```
var animal = e.parameter.animal;
var vegetable= e.parameter.vegetable;
var mineral = e.parameter.mineral ;

html.animal1= animal
html.vegetable1=vegetable
html.mineral1 =mineral
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="input-field col s6">
 <input id="animal1" type="text" value="<?=animal1?>" class="validate" required>
 <label for="animal1"><span class="white-text"><SPAN STYLE="font-size:12.0pt">
  <b>What Type of Animal?</b></span></label>
  </div>
```

However using the same method for Select Options hasn't yielded anything positive.

HTML:

```
 <div class ="row">
 <div class="input-field col s12">
 <select id ="sports1" >
 <option value="null" disabled selected>Which Sport Do You Enjoy?</option>
      <option value="1">Football</option>
      <option value="2">Rugby</option>
      <option value="3">Basketball</option>
      </select>
 <label class="white-text"><i>Love Sport?</i></label>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Have tried within the doGet() the following:=

```
var sport =  e.parameter.sport;

html.sports1 = sport 

sports1.value = sport

$('#sports1').val(sport);

let element = html.getElementById(sports1);
element.value = sport;

let element = document.getElementById(sports1);
element.value = sport;
```

As new to coding can imagine that some of these don't work outside of the HTML JS. However would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Can you provide more information on your script? Where does the var `html` com from?

Comment: var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");

page is my html file

Comment: Something  is better than nothing, but nothing is better than nonsense. Please don't post nonsense. If you know htmljs and jquery doesn't work server side, why post such nonsense code? Just to fill up the space?

Comment: Apologies, but as new to coding wanted to show that I'd tried and learnt about various methods. Didn't want to appear as someone that hadn't initially thought about the issue.